# Convert Promise to Observable in ngrx Effect

Tags: angular, redux, promise, ngrx

I'm using third party library which give promises, but i need to wrap it to Observable in ngrx effect. 
The idea is to dispatch new action when app is initialized successfully. 
But i need to dispatch the data when the promise is resolved.

```
classOne.promise().then(result =>
  nested.OnemorePromise(result).then(result2 =>
    //(result2) dispatch new action here (result2)
  )
);
```

I created something like this:

```js
@Effect()
  initializeValue$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofAction(AppInitializeAction),
    map(action => {
      classOne.promise().then(result =>
      nested.OnemorePromise(result).then(result2 =>
         this.store.dispatch(new Action(result2))
// ideally just - return new Action(result2)
      )
    );
    })
```

It gives me error - effect is dispatch wrong action.

upd:

```js
 @Effect()
  initializeValue$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofAction(AppInitializeAction),
    map(action => {
      return from(classOne.promise()).map(result => {
         console.log(result)
        })
    })
  );
```

map is not a function.

Comment: If you use Rxjs 6, operators are *lettable*, meaning you should 'pipe' them - `from(classOne.promise()).pipe(map(result`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `from` in **Rxjs >= 6**:

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';

map(action => {
  from(classOne.promise()).map(result ...
```

`fromPromise` in **Rxjs <= 5**:

```
import { fromPromise } from 'rxjs/observable/fromPromise';

map(action => {
  fromPromise(classOne.promise()).map(result ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're not returning an `Action`, but you're calling `store.dispatch` manually (just like what your comment says).

To fix this, use `from(promise)` instead of `.promise().then(...)`.

Also make sure the `map` function returns something, which is not the case now.

Comment: i tried to return. the same result. Ok thanks will check